# error: The local variable str(string which i declared) may not have been initialized

Tags: java

I have been trying this but couldn't make out the above error for the program below

```
enter code here

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class mainfunction
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    StringBuffer str;
    StringBuffer ptr;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=input.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
     str=new StringBuffer(new StringBuffer(args[i]));
        for(int j=0;j<t;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k>t;k++)
            {
             ptr=str.reverse();
                if(str.equals(ptr))
                {
                    break;  
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    String prt=str.toString();
        System.out.println(prt.length());
    System.out.println(prt.charAt(prt.length())/2);
}
}
```

how to resolve the issue error stating :

> The local variable str may not have been initialised .please send the
>   appropriate response

Answer (score 2):

***How to resolve the issue error stating : The local variable str may not have been initialized***

Declare your `StringBuffer` as:

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer ptr = new StringBuffer();
```

By doing this means, you have initialized `str` and `ptr` to their default value

Answer (score 1):

That's because `StringBuffer str;` is declared not initialized. You initialize it only inside the `for` loop which is conditional and in case the condition doesn't satisfy, the loop may not be executed, leaving `str` un-initialized.

And that is why you get the error `The local variable str may not have been initialised` on this line, `String prt=str.toString();`.

Initialize it to either `null` or a new `StringBuffer`, just in case, the `for` loop condition doesn't satisfy.

```
StringBuffer str = null; // Either this
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer(); // or this
```

The same would apply to `ptr` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the loop

```
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
```

may not execute, `str` may be `null` at

```
String prt=str.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
StringBuffer str;
StringBuffer ptr;
```

Initialize them first

```
StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer ptr=new StringBuffer();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't initialize undefined variables inside an array as it is not sure whether you will get into array.Try initializing it before,

```
StringBuffer str=null; // and then go ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization only happens when your loop is executed. 
if t=0, the initialization never happens.